# Check if entity is new in EF 4.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I need to check if an entity is new. If it was an int/identity primary key, I could just check if the property for the key has a default value...but in the case of a Guid, I can't do this. Is there anything I can do with the ObjectContext or ObjectStateManager to have it check and determine if the entity in question is new vs. modified?

Comment: Just an idea: Does it create it is as Guid.Empty? If not then check down your layers to see what is stored underneath.

Answer (score 2):

[ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738902.aspx)

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    ObjectStateManager objectStateManager = context.ObjectStateManager;
    EntityState state = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(obj).State;
}
```

Comment: But if it's a new, non-proxy, POCO entity, it won't be in the ObjectStateManager yet...

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a Guid you can do this

```
if(foo.GuidProperty == default(Guid))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a nullable Guid, you can check if it has a value:

```
if (entity.MyGuid.HasValue)
{
  // hooray!
}
```

If it's not nullable, check for default value or an empty GUID:

```
if (entity.MyGuid != default(Guid))
{
  // hooray!
}

if (entity.MyGuid != Guid.Empty)
{
  // hooray!
}
```

Comment: But it's not an identity column (ie. the client code is responsible for assigning the Guid PK value).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand where you're going with this.  In my example, this Guid property doesn't have to be an identity column.